# How to Disable Windows Phone 8 Keyboard buttons?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm working on windows phone 8 textBox where i just change the inputscope of the textbox to number/digits. Problem is there is no use of dot(decimal point) button in the textbox so i want to disable the dot button or when user click on that button it does not reflect in the textbox  i need to input only numbers. So Please help me in this Problem as i'm beginner. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just attach to the `TextBox.KeyDown` event and set it to `Handled = true` when a `.` is inputed, like this:

```cs
private void MyTextBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PlatformKeyCode == 190)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The code for `.` is 190

Comment: Thank a lot yeah thats what i want :)

Comment: Can't we stop keyboard from popup when textbox got focus, i mean if i want to create my own keyboard view which is possible only when default keyboard do not popup on focus

Comment: If you want to create your own keyboard, then I suggest you just don't use a `TextBox` control! Just create your own textbox control or change the Template for a TextBox (more advanced approach!).

Comment: Can we hide the content of the dot(.) button as there is no requirement of this.. as u may have seen it in wallet app to set pin?